# Angular - best way (for performance) to update view based on service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-observable

I have uiSettings service, which based on user data will control parts of templates (in different places).

Currently I use this service directly from template. for example:

```
<li *ngIf="uiService.demoButton()">
      <button [routerLink]="/demo" class="secondary">Demo</button>
</li>
```

In Service:

```
demoButton():boolean {
    return this.demoButtonAvailable;
  }
```

Above property is updated only when something changes for the user (login, logout, update..), but template calls the uiService.demoButton() every second or so.

I believe there is a better way (for performance) to do it.
If I use observable, would I observe this value, or wait for event fired after the needed variable is updated?

Comment: I recommend you to use an observable to track the state of the button and subscribe to it conditionally, it is not recommended to bind functions in template since they run on every angular application tick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` and `async` pipe to notify when something change. You can then use `changeDetectionStrategy: ChangeDetection.onPush` or detach `changeDetectorRef` and detect changes manually.

Comment: Thanks for putting me in right direction. I just need to read more about this BehaviorSubjects. One question. If will update property responsible for that ngIf inside component only when change in service is detected, but still use ngIf in that template, will I gain any performance? (ngIf checking property from self-component instead of service) ?

Comment: I am not sure but as far as I know, Angular run change detection on every event or when some properties change. First you shouldn't use methods (specially methods which take  a lot time to complete) in `*ngIf` - better to use just variable. Second, there shouldn't be much performance difference when property belongs to service. However You should use variables in your template that belongs to your component so using `BehaviorSubject` to store that data in your service would be better option (when value change every subscriber will be notified). Why do you need to optimize it so badly?

Answer (score 0):

ngIf condition runs on every change detection, you need to wrap it with some conditional variable. For example

```
<li *ngIf="demoButtonAvailable">
      <button (click)="uiService.demoButton()" class="secondary">Demo</button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use the service variable `demoButtonAvailable` like below,

```
...

<li *ngIf="uiService.demoButtonAvailable">
      <button [routerLink]="/demo" class="secondary">Demo</button>
</li>

...
```

> *If I use observable, would I observe this value, or wait for event fired after the needed variable is updated?*

You don't need to use `Observable` with `event` for a simple Boolean. YES, it will trigger every time because it's `method call in the view` ( which is not recommended), but you can use service boolean variable unless you want another component variable with service data.

Comment: Is checking boolean property of a service better (faster) than calling a function in that service? And what if I will have, let's say, 10 different places that will display based on data from that service?

Comment: yes,  definitely. If you call that 10 different places there is no difference.